# How do I map all active wireless devices inbound?

Tags: network, wireless

In any residential building, there is a multitude of WPA2-protected wireless access points.

Yesterday I was at a friend's and attempted to launch `aircrack-ng` against their AP (with permission). I was assured that there is a linux laptop currently connected. However, I was unable to acquire the device's MAC, to pass to `aircrack-ng`.

**I would like to acquire a list of all wireless devices inbound, with their respective MAC and IP. If this is possible. I do not have the WPA2 password.**

I know that the first step is to put my network card in [monitor mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode).

```
# airmon-ng <start|stop> <interface> [channel] or airmon-ng <check|check kill> 
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 2
```

As a second step, I attempted `iwlist scan`. However, this returned only a list of AP-s, that is, devices in Master mode.

*Is there some communication between a connected device and the respective AP if no services are running, just to keep the connection alive? How do I monitor this traffic?*

Can I use something line `tcpdump wlan0` to do this? If yes, how can I get the MAC data out of the packets?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for help regarding the usage and operation of specific tools in a specific case. Such information is freely available all over the Internet. Voted to close.

Comment: @Adnan, well, I am asking **which tools to use**. Reading manuals, while pedagogical, is very time consuming, if the manual refers to the wrong tool.

Comment: Plus, I am asking if there exists ongoing communication between a (passive) authenticated device and the AP. If the answer is "no", then no tool would help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for `airodump-ng (interface)` !

Main steps in short:

1) **Put monitor mode**

```
airmon-ng
```

2) **Dump** (This step is what you are searching for)

```
airodump-ng mon0
```

3) **Generate some traffic**

```
aireplay-ng
```

Wait for the handshake.

4) **Crack it with a list**

Use the John the Ripper as word list to crack the WPA/WP2 password.

```
aircrack-ng -w /pentest/passwords/john/password.lst wpacrack-01.ivs
```

**Here is the full description! (I assume you use BT)**

[backtrack wep crack](http://lifehacker.com/5305094/how-to-crack-a-wi+fi-networks-wep-password-with-backtrack)

[HOWTO : WPA/WPA2 cracking with Back|Track 5](http://samiux.blogspot.hu/2011/05/howto-wpawpa2-cracking-with-backtrack-5.html)

Comment: I was using [this tutorial](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=cracking_wpa) where they assume I know the client's MAC. Will airodump-ng report a device, that is already authenticated prior to my arrival at the scene?

Comment: According to this site [link](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng) !

What's the meaning of the fields displayed by airodump-ng ?
Airodump-ng will display a **list of detected access points**!

Comment: Oh, I get it now - `airodump` listens to any packets, directed at the AP. Then, if I did not capture a valid handshake, use the listed MAC to de-authenticate the client. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Kismet in order to passively scan for wireless devices, it comes with Kali Linux distribution (formerly Backtrack).