# Using an active or passive scan, can I detect all devices connected to or transmitting via a Wifi network?

Tags: network, wifi, network-scanners, sniffing, scan

I know that it's possible to do a passive scan on all channels to see if an access point sends a beacon. However, is it also possible to listen to general Wifi traffic on that channel and assemble a list of all active devices - both "clients" (like smartphone or laptop) and access points?

Comment: Something like [airodump-ng](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng) ?

Comment: I can find clients with that, too? I thought airdump-ng is being used to get information from access points.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41817/how-do-i-map-all-active-wireless-devices-inbound?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tools like tshark will show you all the packets on the channel by default. In fact, when doing some analysis, you must apply filters to restrict your search to the useful packets you are interested in (like beacons).